# filter child entities collections with predicate in IOS (objective c )?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i want to set predicate on fire date.

Attribute alerts of entity history is NSorderSet.

[image]

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"History"];    
NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSDate *tempcurrent = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];

// fireTime
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"alerts.fireTime < %@", tempcurrent];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] count];
NSInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
NSLog(@"%li",(long)count);`
```

Problem is Fetched Objects count equal to zero. no data fetched from core data.

Comment: If you don't put the predicate, does it works? The `error` parameter of `countForFetchRequest:error:` says something? It seems that there can be various alerts for a History, so maybe a "ANY" missing (or something like that)?

Comment: Yes it works without any predicate. but with the Predicate it doesn't work and Fetch is zero when predicate set.